# Water and Milk Mixture Problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle

There is a 100 liters of **milk** in a container.

- 5 liters of **milk removed** and replaced with water
- Once again **5 liters of mixture removed** and replaced with water

Now how you calculate to find out the quantity of milk?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a "puzzle" component to this as it's a [straightforward math problem](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably over-simplifying the problem but:

> During step 1, 5 liters of milk are removed and replaced with water producing 100 liters of a 95% milk/5% water mixture

> During step 2, 5 liters of the mixture are removed -> 5 * (95 / 100) of milk = 4.75 liters

> 5 + 4.75 liters = 9.75 liters were removed during the 2 steps, and 90.25 liters of milk remain in the container (with 9.75 liters of water)

Comment: Correct answer.  But yeah simplified 

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. (See my comment under the puzzle)